# How to format modal contents without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm now developing rails app and I've some issues with refreshing modal content without reloading the page.
I have made a modal in my html.erb file and if I click a button, the modal opens and when I click close button during it's steps, the modal closes and the contents of modal(ex: value of input and textarea) are still remaining.
How can I format modal as default without refreshing page.

Here are modal structure

```js
<div class="modal fade new-invest-modal" id="new-investment-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalThree" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="tabs-wrap">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs modal-navs-two" id="myTabTwo" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="start-invest-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#start-invest" role="tab" aria-controls="start-invest" aria-selected="true"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="new-invest-name-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#new-invest-name" role="tab" aria-controls="new-invest-name" aria-selected="false"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContentTwo">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active default-text-wrapper" id="start-invest" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="start-invest-tab">
            <div class="modal-body">
             ...
            </div> <!-- /.modal-body -->
          </div> <!-- /.tab-pane -->

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="new-invest-name" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="new-invest-name-tab">
            <div class="main-container clearfix">
            ...
            </div> <!-- /.main-container -->
         </div> <!-- /.tab-pane -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

Tell me the way as simple. Thanks

Comment: Can you post modal code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to override modal `opening` functionality to make this work.

let's say you've an input field as:

`<div class="modal fade new-modal" id="test-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

 <input type="text" id="test-input" value="test">`

you'll have to use JQuery to override it's functionality.

let's also assume your modal id is something like `test-modal`

```
$('#test-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e){//shown.bs.modal will
                                                   //trigger before modal is opened.
  $('#test-input').val('');//this will make the values in the input field empty
});
```